# Breathing through the mouth

Tags: jogging, breathing

Is breathing through the mouth while jogging bad? I find it difficult to close my mouth while jogging. Some sources claim that breathing while exercising should only be done through the nose while some claim that breathing through the mouth will involve intake of a larger quantity of oxygen. This argument sounds correct.

But, breathing through the mouth does not filter out the dust inhaled. This sounds like a favourable argument for the first claim.

So which one is actually true?

My source for the first claim are regular joggers who I personally know. I'm new to jogging(never seriously considered it over my entire life until now).

[source for second claim](https://runnersconnect.net/running-advice/nose-breathing-while-running-how-to-breathe-properly-while-running/)

Comment: Define "bad". People breathe through their mouths all the time.

Comment: Is inhaling through the mouth not good for health? 'Bad' as in not advisable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are new to jogging just breathe naturally through your mouth. It's the best way to get oxygen in and CO<sub>2</sub> out. Wait until your cardiovascular system get conditioned to try the nose/mouth technique